# java equivalent to the perl URI::QueryParam module

Tags: java, perl, url

Is there an equivalent library for parsing url query params in java?

In order to illustrate what i want i send a code example:

```
use URI;
use URI::QueryParam;

$u = URI->new("http://www.google.com?a=b&c=d");
print $u->query,"\n";    # prints foo=1&foo=2&foo=3

for my $key ($u->query_param) {
    print "$key: ", join(", ", $u->query_param($key)), "\n";
}
```

The output is:

> a=b&c=d
>
> a: b
>
> c: d

I don't like to write my own functions of query fragment parsing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not exactly that but close to:

```
final URI uri = URI.create(inputString);
final String[] queryParams = uri.getQuery().split("&");
```

You'd then split again on `"="` each of the elements of `queryParams`.

---

NOTE: do NOT use `URLDecoder` directly to decode the values of query fragments; it will turn `+` into spaces, [which is wrong according to the URI spec](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3986#section-3.4) (`pchar` contains `sub-delim` contains `+`!)

An approaching solution would be to:

```
URLDecoder.decode(param.replace("+", "%2b"), "UTF-8")
```

To encode, use Guava's `UrlPathSegmentEscaper`.

Demonstration: this simple main:

```
public static void main(final String... args)
    throws UnsupportedEncodingException, URISyntaxException
{
    System.out.println(URLDecoder.decode("a+b", "UTF-8"));
    System.out.println(new URI("http", "foo.bar", "/baz", "op=a+b", null));
    System.out.println(new URI("http", "foo.bar", "/baz", "op=a b", null));
}
```

prints:

```
a b // WRONG!
http://foo.bar/baz?op=a+b
http://foo.bar/baz?op=a%20b
```

Comment: (+1), and then use `URLDecoder` to decode not-portable symbols encoded using   % and their code.

Comment: no, I have just tried this. `getQuery()` does not decode anything. It tried `aaa+bbb` and `aaa%20bbb` and both returned without decoding. Moreover it even *cannot* decode because URL is not for HTTP URLs only. It is theoretically intended for any type of URL while such syntax of parameters encoding is HTTP specific.

Comment: @fge, Re "`.getQuery()` will have decoded all that for you", That's impossible. `getQuery` necessarily returns the query still encoded because the components could contains `&` and `=`. Your solution is incomplete.

Comment: @fge, Re "`URLDecoder` is for form data, not URI query string components", That's wrong. It's not for (all) forms, and it is for query strings.  It's used to parse `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` strings, which is used by query strings and by some (but not all) forms.

Comment: @ikegami the list of characters to decode (and more particularly encode) for URI components differs from `application/x-www-form-urlencoded`

Comment: @fge, You are mistaken. The query string is encoded using `application/x-www-form-urlencoded`, so it can't possibly be encoded differently than `application/x-www-form-urlencoded`. See the [relevant passage](http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/interact/forms.html#h-17.13.3.4) of the spec.

Comment: Back on subject, you still haven't completed your answer. You say we shouldn't use URLDecoder, then show what should be used.

Comment: @ikegami you are mistaken, see the [relevant passage](http://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc3986#section-3.4) and see the grammar for `pchar`: no `+`!

Comment: @fge, No idea what you're saying. `pchar` can be `+`. And you're looking at the wrong spec. The OP asked to process a query form. That's a subset of possible query strings. (Yes, I used the wrong wording earlier.)

Comment: @ikegami `+` is _not_ encoded in a query fragment. Ohwell, nevermind.

Comment: @fge, Actually, `+` does need to be encoded unless it's "used by scheme-specific and producer-specific algorithms for delimiting data subcomponents within a URI" (e.g. used by x-www-form-urlencoded).

Comment: @ikegami NOT in URI queries; it is in FORM data, but this is not form data, this is a URI. See edit...

Comment: Yes, you must. I quoted your very own RFC.

Comment: I see your update. It give the wrong answer for `?q=foo+bar`. As RFC3986 says, `+` is a `reserved_char`. It has a special meaning when it's not escaped. See [here](http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/interact/forms.html#h-17.13.3.4) for what it means. Just look at what FF and Chrome do when you place `foo+bar` in a text field. It produces `q=foo%2Bbar` because `q=foo+bar` means something else.

Answer (score 1):

What's wrong with `java.net.URL` and `java.net.URI`?

Comment: There is nothing wrong with it, but it gives me just the query string with the getQuery function. Then i have to write my own function to parse it. We have also to keep in mind that there are parameters with multiple values.

Comment: @DavidMichaelGang, take a look on answer given by fge and my comment to his answer. This gives you complete solution.